# how to traverse inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
{% for location in locationcheck %}
<input style="float:left;" type="button" class="delete"/>
<label><input style="margin: 0 10px 0 10px;" type="checkbox" checked="True" name="sub_location_key">{{ location }}</label>
<button type="button" style="margin: 1px 120px;" name="delete" id="{{ location.id }}" class="sublocation_delete"/>Delete</button><br />
{% endfor %}
```

generated html:

```
 <input style="float:left;" type="button" class="delete"/>
 <label><input style="margin: 0 10px 0 10px;" type="checkbox" checked="True"  value="1234" name="sub_location_key">Playground</label>
 <button type="button" style="margin: 1px 120px;" name="delete" id="1234" class="sublocation_delete"/>Delete</button><br />
```

js:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.siblings(".sublocation_delete").toggle();
```

css:

```
.sublocation_delete {
    display:none;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;    
}
```

The delete class and delete button are dynamically created by program that are more than one.
Onclicking  delete class,the hidden delete button should comes to appear.The above code i tried it is showing all the button on clicking the single "delete" class.

I tried with nextAll,find and closest also nothing worked,may i know what is the correct traverse.

Comment: it will be easier if you can share the generated html instead of a template

Comment: Generated html updated.

Comment: Your button html has a syntax error. `<button ... />Delete</button>` should be `<button ... >Delete</button>

Comment: I don't see anything in your HTML that has a class "delete".

Comment: @andi it was typo error,corrected

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is delegate the listener, like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    //whatever
}
```

This will tell the `<body>` tag to assign this listener to all elements with the class `delete` that are ever created within it. You can do the same for any other element i.e. `$('div#mydiv').on('click', '.delete', function(e){/*whatever*/})`

Also, the class you're assigning in your html is `sublocation_delete`, not just `delete`. So... make sure *that's* consistent, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created elements use jquery .live() method to bind events. Jquery .on() or .click() [or any other event binders] will not work for elements added dynamically. Just try it this way :

```
$(".delete").live('click', function(){
//Whatever you need to do...
});
```

Comment: Eh.. `live` was deprecated back in 1.7'ish and replaced by `on`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (notice I added an ID to the first button and changed the ID for the toggled button):

```
{% for location in locationcheck %}
   <input style="float:left;" type="button" id="{{ location.id }}" class="delete"/>
   <label><input style="margin: 0 10px 0 10px;" type="checkbox" checked="True" name="sub_location_key">{{ location }}</label>
   <button type="button" style="margin: 1px 120px;" name="delete" id="btn_{{ location.id }}" class="sublocation_delete"/>Delete</button><br />
{% endfor %}
```

JS:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $("#btn_" + $this.attr("id")).toggle();  
}
```